# Using Chromium v52, Chromecast no longer works and can't find device

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, chromecast

On the prior version of Chromium the Chromecast extension could find my Google Chromecast v2 devices. Now it can't and it says it can not find any devices when I try to cast. What's going on and how to I fix it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*Works at least with Version 55.0 (the version shipped with 16.10).*

So there are two ways to cast to *Chromecast*

- one of them is with the *extension*
- the other one is with the *native functionality*.

This should work natively with **Google Chrome**.

I do not believe **Chromium** supports the native cast. Disabling this native feature opens up the ability to use the extension. Or you can use *Google Chrome*.

1. Open up `chrome://flags/#media-router`, it should say **Media Router Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS:** *Enables Chrome to access external presentation-type displays and use them for presenting web content. #media-router*
2. Change it from `Default` to `Disabled`
3. Restart chromium-browser
4. Install Google Cast extension if necessary

This should work. There is a [Launchpad bug opened here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1621753). The answer is based off Bob Smith's suggestion on this [Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=833477#34). You can now see this advice in the official faq [How to turn off Media Router and use the Google Cast extension](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6349849).

Comment: Can confirm that it works.

Comment: This apparently doesn't work as of at least yesterday (Jan 24th, 2017): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1621753/comments/6

Comment: Still working for me.

Comment: Well, it's not working for me, @EvanCarroll. You probably just haven't updated and restarted your browser yet.

Comment: K bruh, *Version 55.0.2883.87 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.10 (64-bit)*

Comment: @EvanCarroll Version 57.0.2950.4 Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit) can confirm I dont even have that flag anymore, work laptop with same version as yours does still work though

Comment: I can confirm that with Chromium 56.0.2924.76, it doesn't work even with the workaround. In fact, the specific "switch" to turn off in the media-router settings no longer exists. Chrome still works though.

Comment: Google won't let me installed [the chromecast extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd) anymore, with either the media router flag disabled or default. Any idea if using chromecast is still an option?

Comment: Not working here on Papa Debian either. 57.0.2987.98 built on Debian 9.0, running on Debian 9.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score 22):

I am using chromium Version 57.0.2987.98, Ubuntu 17.04 (64-bit). The native "Cast..." does not work until you enable this flag below. Once its enabled, it works perfect, no need for any extension.

chrome://flags/#load-media-router-component-extension

Comment: yep, works for me on debian 8.7 with chromium 57.0.2987.98. The other answer said to *disable*, but i found that only *enabling* the property you list works.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Chromium 58.0.3029.110 confirmed solution.

Comment: This also works for me on Gentoo and Chromium 59.0.3071.104. I'd note that I had to change the setting from "Default" to "Enabled" and restart the browser.

Comment: Confirmed on Slackware64-14.2 and Chromium Version 62.0.3202.75 (Developer Build) (64-bit).  This appears to be the correct answer as of February 2018.

Comment: I also had to enable `#media-router-cast-allow-all-ips` for my Chromium 74.0.3729.131 to work.

Comment: Is there an upstream bug for this? It seems incredible to have such a large feature completely non-functional, with no user-visible messaging that it is non-functional, by default.