# Can't see any Chromecast device

Tags: lubuntu, chromium, iptables, chromecast

I have Lubuntu 16.10 32bit and Chromium. I have configured iptables as follows:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 32768:61000 -j ACCEPT

ivan@ivan-HP-Lubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpts:32768:61000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

But I can't see any of my Chromecast devices. Any suggestion?

Comment: it may out of your questions but just a suggestion, have you check in your chrome browser to ensure google cast extension is installed?

Comment: I switched to Lubuntu 64bit, installed Chrome and it worked nicely out-of-the-box.

Comment: I see. maybe the 32-bit have the issues. you may asked in chat group if got questions that maybe off-topic here.

Comment: I had trouble with Chromium but this fixed it for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/908074/294281

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Chromecast Ultra. Just did it without specifing ports (which helped)

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp -j ACCEPT
```