# Using Chromecast on Chromium v52 and above

Tags: chromium, chromecast

The issue detailed in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825903/using-chromium-v52-chromecast-no-longer-works-and-cant-find-device) is still happening, however the solution presented is no longer relevant since [the Google Cast extension has been discontinued](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd). Is there a way to keep using Chromecast from Chromium, or is it no longer possible at all?

(As a side note, I would like to mention that I initially wanted to participate in the initial thread so as to avoid duplicate threads but I could neither add comment (50+ reputation points required) nor an answer (10+ reputation points required) and therefore I was advised to open a new thread instead.)

Answer (score 2):

casting is available is part of chromium now. There is no need to install any update.

More details can be found in the below link:

https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/6398952?hl=en&ref_topic=4602553

Comment: That page relates to Chrome though, not Chromium

Comment: Chromium seems to have the `cast...` menu, at least for version Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit), and it's working with my tv.